# Use Eloquent to define a filtered relationship with group by and most recent date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4- I'm trying really hard to use Eloquent's relationship model to return a query within my view instead of running a static database query. I'm sure I could use the group by join method, but I know there's *gotta* be a way within the model to just define it.

In short, my log_contents table has multiple views to log when a user views an article.

Example data:

```
|  id  | content_id | action | created_at |
-------------------------------------------
|   1  |          2 |  View  | 10:30:00   |
|   2  |          2 |  View  | 10:31:00   |
|   3  |          5 |  View  | 08:32:00   |
|   4  |          2 |  View  | 13:59:00   |
|   5  |          3 |  Like  | 12:14:00   |
```

This is the function I have **so far** which returns apparently the first instance of the content_id for each group:

```
public function articlesViewed()
{
    return $this->hasMany('LogContent')
                ->where('content_type', '=', 'Article')
                ->whereAction('View')
                ->groupBy('content_id')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

but the problem is I want it to return the **most recent** record, so that in the case of content_id=2, it would return row id 4, but right now it's returning row id 1.

Can I do this with eloquent's relationship model? or do I have to do it using the static query LogContent::et('cetera').

Comment: ad MAX (`created_at`) to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical mysql query problem, you want to orderBy first then groupBy the results. And with eloquent it is easier to implement this. You should use query scopes. In your `LogContent` model, you should have following:

```
public function scopeMostRecent($query)
{
    return $query->join(DB::raw('(SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY created_at DESC) as b'), function($join) {
                $join->on('table_name.id', '=', 'b.id');
           })->groupBy('content_id');
}
```

And in your articleViewed() method:

```
public function articlesViewed()
{
    return $this->hasMany('LogContent')
                ->mostRecent()
                ->where(''content_type', '=', 'Article')
                ->whereAction('View')
                ->get();
}
```

Comment: your function makes a lot of sense- but i'm getting an error within the function($join): "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::orderBy()"

Comment: @mydoglixu my mistake, it should join to a subquery, not the same table. I have updated the query, please try again and let me know.

Comment: you did more than help! I was stuck on this for way too long :)